# Lucene.net search only for distinct column values

Tags: c#, lucene, distinct, lucene.net

I am using Lucene.net search and my hash table looks like:

```
ID    |    Customer    |    Update
1     |    name1       |    hello
1     |    name1       |    hello again
2     |    name2       |    how r u
3     |    name3       |    hi
3     |    name3       |    it is not working
```

What I want is, when I search for "hello" I get result list distinct by ID:

```
ID    |    Customer    |    Update
1     |    name1       |    "hello"
```

I do not need update column to be in result (therefor I don't care which update of ID 1 will be in result) I just want it searchable. The only result I need is ID and name of customer. I know I can do this by using `result.DistinctBy(res => res.Id)` from [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) but I want `IndexSearcher` to search only for dictinct Id values. Is there any way I can achieve this without calling LINQ on results? Maybe using searcher argument filter?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

There's no way (that I know of) of having Lucene the distinct internally.

However, there is a more efficient approach.

The Linq method means that you must fully project your rows/objects which might be expensive if there are more fields in the real thing.

If you add a Sort the the query so that Lucene returns the docs in id order you could just project the id, ad only project the rest of the doc if the id is different than the previous.

It's a custom method but that's pretty normal.